# PHP compare two arrays but foreach around them (or alt method)

Tags: php, arrays

So i have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Page] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )

            [PageRevision] => Array
                (
                    [PageId] => 1
                    [PageRevisionId] => 3
                    [goldMaster] => 0
                )

            [PageLanguage] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Contact Page
                )

            [PageSetting] => Array
                (
                    [url] => contact2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Page] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )

            [PageRevision] => Array
                (
                    [PageId] => 1
                    [PageRevisionId] => 2
                    [goldMaster] => 1
                )

            [PageLanguage] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Contact Page 2
                )

            [PageSetting] => Array
                (
                    [url] => contact
                )

        )

)
```

What i need to do is determine , out of the two array given, if one of them has a higher PageRevisionId than the other one and if it's goldMaster is set to 0. But i am struggling to find any method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($array[0]['PageRevision']['PageRevisionId'] > $array[1]['PageRevision']['PageRevisionId']
&& $array[0]['PageRevision']['goldMaster'] == 0) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: But i dont know what order they will be in, so $array2 could have the goldMaster set to 0 and i wouldnt know, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code with an unlimited number of element in you main array:

```
$max_pageRevisionId = 0;
$max_goldMaster = 0;

foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
    if($value['PageRevision']['PageRevisionId'] > $max_pageRevisionId) {
        $max_pageRevisionId = $value['PageRevision']['PageRevisionId'];
        $max_goldMaster = $value['PageRevision']['goldMaster'];
    }
}

if($max_goldMaster > 0) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$elem = ($array [0]['PageRevision']['PageRevisionId'] > $array [1]['PageRevision']['PageRevisionId'])?
 1:
 0;

var_dump ($array [0]['PageRevision']['goldMaster '] == 0)
```